# write in excel fom html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the html table value and write it into an excel.
The values for the table are got for a query.
This is my html table written in style sheet:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <table id="table" border="2" style="top:230px">
    <tr>
      <td width="200" height="150">
        <xsl:value-of select="agu2a_nb"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td width="200" height="150">
        <xsl:value-of select="pdm_ecn_type"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td width="200" height="150">
        <xsl:value-of select="pdm_project_code"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td width="300" height="150">
        <xsl:value-of select="created_by_id/@keyed_name"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td width="200" height="150">
        <xsl:value-of select="created_on"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
      <td width="200" height="150">
        <xsl:value-of select="state"></xsl:value-of>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to write this table in a predefined excel.
Could anybody advice on how to proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you using as backend php or asp ?

Comment: im using html and javascript to generate a report

Comment: Im able to display my report in html. I have a href to open my excel. Now I want to know how to push these values into this excel.

Comment: did you check this out? http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in files using JavaScript is not possible because JavaScript is a client side language and can't access the file system(can cause security problems),
but instead you can grab the data using JavaScript then send it to a server side script(php,asp etc ) to process it.

Here is a simple example :

```
<body>
  <div>
      <table id="table" border="2" style="top:230px">
          <tr>
                      <td width="200" height="150">
                          <input type="text" id="agu2a_nb">
                      </td>
                     <td width="200" height="150">
                         <input type="text" id="pdm_ecn_type">
                      </td>
                      <td width="200" height="150">
                          <input type="text" id="pdm_project_code">
                      </td>
                      <td width="300" height="150">
                         <input type="text" id="created_by_id">
                      </td>
                      <td width="200" height="150">
                         <input type="text" id="created_on">
                      </td>
                     <td width="200" height="150">
                         <input type="text" id="state">
                      </td>
               </tr>
          </table>

      <input type="submit" id="send" value="send">


      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var obj {};

            $('#send').click(function(){
                obj.agu2a_nb = $('#agu2a_nb').val(),
                obj.pdm_ecn_type = $('#pdm_ecn_type').val(),
                obj.pdm_project_code = $('#pdm_project_code').val(),
                obj.created_by_id = $('#created_by_id').val(),
                obj.created_on = $('#created_on').val(),
                obj.state = $('#state').val();

            });

          $.post('server_side_url',obj,function(response_returned_from_sever){

          });


        });
      </script> 
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But where do I use this code. I use it with in my html(stylesheet)? where is the excel file called in the code?

Comment: I'm new to javascript and dont know php.

Comment: it is okay, first javascript can't be used to create file, 
second go and learn javascript and php then start to play around with them.
Good luck :)